# Does QGIS-Server 3.x+ Still Support Image/SVG as a WMS GetMap FORMAT?

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server

Specifying `FORMAT=image/svg` for WMS layer exports returns
`The format 'image/svg' from FORMAT is not supported.`
and [The latest QGIS-Server 3.22 Web Map Service (WMS) Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/services/wms.html) isn't too clear either.

Current search on the issue is mostly about svg print-composer and svg icon symbology not WMS image output FORMAT. With only excepted [GitHub issue from 2014 for QGIS-Server 2.xx](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/18538) for a user who was successful exporting svg for version 2.xx.

Also tried altering the `VERSION` parameter in the WMS url to `1.0.0, 1.1.0 and 1.3.0` to success.

Edit:
Here is the output of the `REQUEST=GetProjectSettings`:

```
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/wms" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/sld_capabilities.xsd http://www.qgis.org/wms http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetSchemaExtension">
<Service>
<Name>WMS</Name>
<Title>MDG Water Access Indicator</Title>
<Abstract>
<![CDATA[ The proportion of the population with sustainable access to an improved water source, urban and rural, is the percentage of the population who use any of the following types of water supply for drinking: – piped water, – public tap, – borehole or pump, – protected well, – protected spring or – rainwater. ]]>
</Abstract>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword vocabulary="ISO">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="www.mwe.go.ug" xlink:type="simple"/>
<ContactInformation>
<ContactPersonPrimary>
<ContactPerson>unknown</ContactPerson>
<ContactOrganization>Ministry of Water and Environmnet</ContactOrganization>
</ContactPersonPrimary>
</ContactInformation>
<Fees>conditions unknown</Fees>
<AccessConstraints>None</AccessConstraints>
</Service>
<Capability>
<Request>
<GetCapabilities>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetCapabilities>
<GetMap>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=16bit</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=1bit</Format>
<Format>application/dxf</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetMap>
<GetFeatureInfo>
<Format>text/plain</Format>
<Format>text/html</Format>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
<Format>application/json</Format>
<Format>application/geo+json</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetFeatureInfo>
<sld:GetLegendGraphic>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>application/json</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</sld:GetLegendGraphic>
<sld:DescribeLayer>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</sld:DescribeLayer>
<qgs:GetStyles>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</qgs:GetStyles>
<GetPrint>
<Format>svg</Format>
<Format>png</Format>
<Format>pdf</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetPrint>
</Request>
<Exception>
<Format>XML</Format>
</Exception>
<sld:UserDefinedSymbolization RemoteWCS="0" SupportSLD="1" UserLayer="0" RemoteWFS="0" InlineFeature="0" UserStyle="1"/>
<ComposerTemplates>
<ComposerTemplate width="297" height="210" name="mdg_access_indicator">
<ComposerMap width="220.452" height="180.1996178343948" name="map0"/>
</ComposerTemplate>
</ComposerTemplates>
<WFSLayers>
<WFSLayer name="MDG Water Access Indicator"/>
</WFSLayers>
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>mdg_indicator_access</Name>
<Title>MDG Water Access Indicator</Title>
<Abstract>
<![CDATA[ The proportion of the population with sustainable access to an improved water source, urban and rural, is the percentage of the population who use any of the following types of water supply for drinking: – piped water, – public tap, – borehole or pump, – protected well, – protected spring or – rainwater. ]]>
</Abstract>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword vocabulary="ISO">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>28.410841</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>36.163678</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>-1.624354</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>4.374192</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox minx="28.41" maxx="36.164" CRS="EPSG:3857" maxy="4.375" miny="-1.625"/>
<TreeName>MDG Water Access Indicator</TreeName>
<Layer geometryType="MultiPolygon" visible="1" queryable="1" displayField="name" opacity="1" expanded="1" visibilityChecked="1">
<Name>MDG Water Access Indicator</Name>
<Title>MDG Water Access Indicator</Title>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>29.573465</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>35.001054</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>-1.481531</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>4.23137</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox minx="3292103.102" maxx="3896299.457" CRS="EPSG:3857" maxy="471462.629" miny="-164941.606"/>
<Style>
<Name>default</Name>
<Title>default</Title>
<LegendURL>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:8001/ows/scan/mdg_access_indicator?MAP=/data/scan/mdg_access_indicator.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&LAYER=MDG Water Access Indicator&FORMAT=image/png&STYLE=default&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0" xlink:type="simple"/>
</LegendURL>
</Style>
<TreeName>MDG Water Access Indicator</TreeName>
<PrimaryKey>
<PrimaryKeyAttribute>district_id</PrimaryKeyAttribute>
</PrimaryKey>
<Attributes>
<Attribute typeName="int4" editType="Range" length="-1" type="int" name="district_id" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="varchar" editType="TextEdit" length="15" type="QString" name="name" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="numeric" editType="TextEdit" length="-1" type="double" name="rural_population" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="numeric" editType="TextEdit" length="-1" type="double" name="urban_population" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="numeric" editType="TextEdit" length="-1" type="double" name="total_population" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="int4" editType="Range" length="-1" type="int" name="rural_population_served" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="int4" editType="Range" length="-1" type="int" name="urban_population_served" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="int4" editType="Range" length="-1" type="int" name="total_population_served" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="float4" editType="TextEdit" length="-1" type="double" name="access_rural" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="float4" editType="TextEdit" length="-1" type="double" name="access_urban" comment="" precision="0"/>
<Attribute typeName="float4" editType="TextEdit" length="-1" type="double" name="access_total" comment="" precision="0"/>
</Attributes>
</Layer>
</Layer>
<LayerDrawingOrder>MDG Water Access Indicator</LayerDrawingOrder>
</Capability>
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

Comment: Is your layer a vector layer and how is it configured?

Comment: Yes it is a vector and I have edited the question to include GetProjectSettings out.

Comment: The SVG format is only available in GetPrint requests as you can see in the GetCapabilities response.

Comment: Does this mean QGIS-Server in general nolonger supports the SVG format in its GetMap WMS REQUEST service? Like other mapservers.

Comment: The GetMap format list in GetCapabilities is where you can get the information. That server does not support SVG as GetMap format. Many other WMS servers indeed support SVG as a GetMap format but it is the choice of the developers. WMS standard does not mandate any output format.

Comment: Thanks, I have went ahead to issue it as a GitHub [feature request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50490) at the QGIS Repo.